# How to get chart type of a particular chart using Open XML SDK?

Tags: c#, excel, xml-parsing, charts, openxml-sdk

I have an Excel file with a chart in it.

I am able to reference the chart using the chartPart property provided by Open XML SDK.

How do I obtain the type of chart (bar, pie,line,etc.) from this?

**P.S.** I have looked through the structure of this chartPart variable but I've been unable to figure out where exactly to find the information such as Type, Axis, Color, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection concept you get chart types

```
private IEnumerable<Type> GetExcelChartTypes()
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> items = new List<Type>();
            try
            {
                DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.LineChart linechart = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Charts.LineChart();
                items = Assembly.GetAssembly(linechart.GetType()).GetTypes().Where(S => S.Name.EndsWith("Chart"));
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return items;
        }
```

before doing so get all the chart parts with

> IEnumerable chartparts =
>   spreadsheet.DrawingsPart.ChartParts;

then get chart object with the below line

> IEnumerable
>   charts =
>   chartpart.ChartSpace.ChildElements.OfType();
>   .

Each chart object will have plot area object get that and get Type of object with GetType().

Then certainly you will get name of the chart.

Comment: Hi, is there a direct implementation of this? I am still not able to get the type of chart using this..